# Not accepting the access key that I need to connect to DynamoDB

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell

Quick question about this error since most of the references are more than 2-3 years old, I just want to have a good understanding of what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please remove your access and secret key from the screenshot

Comment: It's normally better if you can cut&paste the *text* of your error rather than a screenshot - it helps other people find your question in google if they're having the same issue, and it means we don't have to re-type the error if we're trying  to research the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the [AmazonDynamoDBCmdlets](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AmazonDynamoDBCmdlets), in which case you can get help on the parameters for the `Connect-AmazonDynamoDB` cmdlet as follows:

```
PS> import-module C:\amazondynamodbcmdlets.19.0.7354\AmazonDynamoDBCmdlets.psd1
PS> get-help connect-amazondynamodb

NAME
    Connect-AmazonDynamoDB

SYNTAX
    Connect-AmazonDynamoDB [-AccessKey <string>] [-AutoCache] [-AutoDetectIndex <bool>] [-BufferSize <string>] [-CacheConnection <string>] [-CacheLocation <string>] [-CacheMetadata] [-CacheProvider <string>] [-CacheTolerance <string>] [-CredentialsFileLocation <string>] [-Domain <string>] [-FirewallPassword <string>] [-FirewallPort <string>] [-FirewallServer <string>] [-FirewallType {NONE | TUNNEL | SOCKS4 | SOCKS5}] [-FirewallUser <string>] [-FlattenArrays <string>] [-FlattenObjects <bool>] [-GenerateSchemaFiles {Never | OnUse | OnStart}] [-InsertMode {REPLACE | DONTREPLACE}] [-Location <string>] [-Logfile <string>] [-MaximumRequestRetries <string>] [-MaxLogFileCount <string>] [-MaxLogFileSize <string>] [-MaxRows <string>] [-MFASerialNumber <string>] [-MFAToken <string>] [-NumberColumnMode {DOUBLE | DECIMAL | STRING}] [-Offline] [-Other <string>] [-Pagesize <string>] [-ProxyAuthScheme {BASIC | DIGEST | NONE | NEGOTIATE | NTLM | PROPRIETARY}] [-ProxyAutoDetect <bool>]
    [-ProxyExceptions <string>] [-ProxyPassword <string>] [-ProxyPort <string>] [-ProxyServer <string>] [-ProxySSLType {AUTO | ALWAYS | NEVER | TUNNEL}] [-ProxyUser <string>] [-PseudoColumns <string>] [-Readonly] [-Region {NORTHERNVIRGINIA | OHIO | NORTHERNCALIFORNIA | OREGON | CENTRAL | IRELAND | FRANKFURT | LONDON | SINGAPORE | SYDNEY | SEOUL | TOKYO | MUMBAI | SAOPAULO | BEIJING | GOVCLOUDWEST | PARIS | NIGXIA | OSAKA-LOCAL}] [-RetryWaitTime <string>] [-RoleARN <string>] [-RowScanDepth <string>] [-RTK <string>] [-SecretKey <string>] [-SeparatorCharacter <string>] [-SSLServerCert <string>] [-SupportEnhancedSQL <bool>] [-Tables <string>] [-TemporaryTokenDuration <string>] [-ThreadCount <string>] [-Timeout <string>] [-TypeDetectionScheme {None | RowScan}] [-URL <string>] [-UseEC2Roles] [-UseSimpleNames] [-Verbosity <string>] [-Views <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

If you compare that to your command...

```
$amazondynamodb = Connect-AmazonDynamoDB -Access Key "$accessKey" -Secret Key -Domain "$secretKey" -Domain "$domainName" -Region "$regionName"
```

...you can see your parameter names `-Access Key` and `-Secret Key` shouldn't have a space in them.

PowerShell is intepretting your command as a parameter called `-Access` with a value `Key` and another *postional* parameter after with your intended parameter value, with the same issue for the `-SecretKey` parameter as well.

Remove the spaces and you'll at least be invoking the command correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, this is really helpful. May I ask if you know a better way to access dynamoDB data using powershell?